# Error in fitting models with depmixS4 in R - Error in if (sum(fbo$gamma[, i]) > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a model using depmixS4 package in R. I have a total of 13,300 rows and 43 columns. But when I am fitting the model, I am getting an error - Error in if (sum(fbo$gamma[, i]) > 0) { :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed. However, if I reduce the number of rows (say 2000), then it fits the model. My code to fit the model is -
fit(mod, verbose=TRUE, emcontrol=em.control(classification = 'soft'))
Can anyone please help me with fitting this model?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question

Comment: Do you have any missing data in your dependent variable or some observations where the dependent variable is always 0 (FALSE) or more than one 1 (TRUE) for any grouping of the observations? This tend to be what causes the error. In any case, these would be uninformative in the case of 0 so can be dropped or in the case of multiple 1s you need to check for data coding errors.

Comment: All my data columns were positive integers and there were no missing values. But to remove biases, I scaled the data to have a mean 0 and sd 1 for all the columns respectively. 
I tried running the analysis with a smaller subset of the same pre-processed data, and the model converged. It is only throwing an error when I am including the entire dataset into the analysis.